# How to redirect to a URL by some authentications in ODOO

Tags: odoo

Hope you all are doing well.
How can we redirect to a thirdparty URL by some authentications(Parameters) through controller. Means we have some crediantials to access the URL..we need to pass these as parameters..
I am successful in redirecting to URL using `werkzeug.utils.redirect("URL")`, but this does not allow me to use authentications...

Comment: URL with credentials(parameters) can be hit by using REQUEST. You've to make a POST/GET request.

Comment: Hello, I am using POST, but it only post data and give me response=200, but not redirect me to the URL.

Comment: Any idea for this please.

Comment: Can you please give detail of your task like are you developing connector or something else?

Comment: Actually i am integrating payment gateway with Odoo. And we have to redirect on payment gateway site along with some form data which include customer_key and password etc.

Answer (score 0):

Then try this

```
client_id = "My_Client_Id"
return {
    'name': 'Go to website',
    'res_model': 'ir.actions.act_url',
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
    'target': 'self',
    'url': 'https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?user_scope=channels:history,channels:read,'
                   'channels:write,im:write,chat:write&client_id=' + client_id
}
```

> This code will help you or may solve your issue because it is
> redirecting you on given URL with my own data(client Id)

Comment: Hello Adam Strauss,

Comment: Thank you four reply,
I want to redirect to a url along with some form date to access the url, i am using post and redirect methods, but can't access.
Here is my controller. can you review it please,

Comment: I think you're missing something which payment gateway are you integration and at which part are you stuck?

Comment: for example strip at authentication level etc

Comment: Because as per my experience with APIs redirect urls never take form data as a request data is pass as a variable with in a URL